# User Authentication in angular-moviemasher

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-moviemasher

I have integrated angular-moviemasher on my server but whenever I upload an image it gives me an authentication alert asking for username and password. The documentation and the alert indicate that any combination of username and password should be accepted. I have two problems:

- I found no user / pw combination that is accepted
- I want no authentication at all, allowing any user to upload any image

[moviemasher](https://github.com/moviemasher/angular-moviemasher)

[my site](http://bluepenlabs.com/contract9987/plg2/app/)

Comment: Even if I knew angular-moviemasher, I'd have difficulties to figure out what you want and where to start, I guess. Usually, a bit more details are expected: what did you try, where does it fail? Your description is quite generic and broad.

Comment: I have integrate it on my server and i just getting an authentication alert for username and password.From where i will get this username and password and how can i get rid of it..

Comment: As per their site: *by default it uses HTTP authentication that accepts any username and password combination - hardly a recommended mechanism* and you want to allow anyone to upload any image?

Comment: Yes i want to allow anyone to upload images

Comment: And it do not accept any username and password .It accepts nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by having a look at [authutils](https://github.com/moviemasher/angular-moviemasher/blob/master/app/php/include/authutils.php). You need to change `auth_challenge` to not ask for any credentials, `auth_ok` should always be `TRUE` and because you then have no user, you also need to change at least `auth_userid`.

Best approach would be to not alter authutils directly but define the used functions upfront (i.e. implementing a no-auth configuration).

Comment: I have change the auth_ok to "True" but how can i change the auth_challenge so that it do not ask any credentials. 
How can i implement no-auth configuration.Please help

Comment: Getting the below error in import_upload.php
{"error":"Required uid parameters omitted"}

I am sure there might be some problem with the auth_userid.Please help I am new to moviemasher